# Why do I need to use an extra `::` prefix to access an imported struct?

Tags: rust, rust-crates

In my `lib.rs` I wanted to do `use std::fs::File`.

Here is the example code:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;

impl Css { 
    pub fn save_result_to_file(file_to_save: String) {
        println!("Saving output to {}", file_to_save);
        let mut f = File::open(file_to_save).expect("Unable to open file");
        // let mut f = ::File::open(file_to_save).expect("Unable to open file"); -> Works
    }
}
```

Without the presence of `::` before `File` I'm getting a compiler error:

```
|  let mut f = File::open(file_to_save).expect("Unable to open file");
|                         ^^^^^^^^^^ Use of undeclared type or module `File`
```

My question is - is the `::` prefix always necessary? I'm sure it's not, but cannot see how to do this.

Comment: Cannot reproduce; you need to `use std::fs::File;` in the *actual* file where you are calling `File::open`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of the `::` module path separator the same way as `/` in a file path, and just as a leading `/` means the root directory, a leading `::` refers to your application's root module.

When you import an item with `use` then the name of that item effectively becomes a (private by default) member of that module, and can be referred to from other modules using absolute or relative paths. So the fact that you are having this problem tells me that your `use` statements are in your root module, while the other code is in a child module. That is why commenters above were unable to reproduce it from the code you actually posted.

You have some module structure like this:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;

mod Foo {
    struct Css {}
    impl Css { 
        pub fn save_result_to_file(file_to_save: String) {
            println!("Saving output to {}", file_to_save);
            let mut f = ::File::open(file_to_save).expect("Unable to open file");
        }
    }
}
```

The leading `::` is necessary because `File` was imported into the root module, but you are using it in a child module. If you move the import into the actual module that contains your code then it will work fine without the leading `::`:

```
mod Foo {
    use std::fs::File;
    use std::io::Read;

    struct Css {}
    impl Css { 
        pub fn save_result_to_file(file_to_save: String) {
            println!("Saving output to {}", file_to_save);
            let mut f = File::open(file_to_save).expect("Unable to open file");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks - so  when having multiple `mod` in a single file I need to add this to every mod namespace so to say?

Comment: @abdoe Yes that's right. Rust doesn't care about which files the modules live in, it just cares about the module structure.